# Pattern matching in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching

I need to create a variable in JavaScript and assign it's value based on a condition. This works but feels a bit verbose:

```
  const color = (() => {
    switch (type) {
      case "primary":
        return CONSTANTS.colors.primary;
      case "secondary":
        return CONSTANTS.colors.secondary;
      case "tertiary":
        return CONSTANTS.colors.tertiary;
      case "positive":
        return CONSTANTS.colors.positive;
      case "negative":
        return CONSTANTS.colors.negative;
      case "disabled":
        return CONSTANTS.colors.disabled;
      default:
        throw new Error("A backgroundColor condition was missed");
    }
  })();
```

Is what I'm trying to do called "pattern matching"? Ive read that JavaScript doenst have this feature but Im not totally sure what it is.

Is there a more concise way of writing the code above? I could have lots of `if` statement but this feels messier and requires the variable to be `let` not `const`.

```
let color:
if (type === "primary") {
    color = CONSTANTS.colors.primary;
} else if(type === "secondary") {
    color = CONSTANTS.colors.secondary;
} else if(type === "tertiary") {
    color = CONSTANTS.colors.tertiary;
} else if(type === "secondary") {
    color = CONSTANTS.colors.secondary;
} else if(type === "positive") {
    color = CONSTANTS.colors.positive;
} else if(type === "negative") {
    color = CONSTANTS.colors.negative;
} else if(type === "disabled") {
    color = CONSTANTS.colors.disabled;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean JS doesn’t have pattern matching? You seem to be mixing up a few things here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern matching is generally referring to matching arguments passed to a function: testing to see if they match a specific "pattern". For example, a pattern match might allow you to write a function that takes an  integer argument in "two different ways", one where the argument passed in is `0` and one when the argument passed is not `0` (the "otherwise" case). Switch statements are somewhat similar to this type of branching logic but aren't the same as a purely functional language like Haskell, and don't quite help with your goal here.

How about something like this instead?

```
const myColor = CONSTANTS["colors"][type];
if(typeof myColor !== 'undefined') {
    color = myColor;
} else {
   throw new Error("A backgroundColor condition was missed");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution for your problem is to check if the `type` is defined in the object `CONSTANTS.colors`. If you want to access a property by variable, you need to use the bracket annotation. Everything inside the brackets is evaluated as an expression (so `type` is a variable, `'type'` the String value). Therefore, `object.type` returns the same value as `object['type']`.

```
let color = null;
if (typeof CONSTANTS.colors[type] !== 'undefined') {
   color = CONSTANTS.colors[type];
} else {
   throw new Error('A backgroundColor condition was missed');
}
console.log(color);
```

---

You can also first check if the key is defined in the object with `Object.keys()` and `includes()`:

```
let color = null;
if (Object.keys(CONSTANTS.colors).includes(type)) {
    color = CONSTANTS.colors[type];
} else {
   throw new Error('A backgroundColor condition was missed');
}
console.log(color);
```

If you want to support IE11, you [cannot use `.includes()`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes). Use `.indexOf(type) !== -1` instead of `.includes(type)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```
color = CONSTANTS.colors[type];
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy replacement for your code would be

```
const color = (() => {
    const color = CONSTANTS.colors[type];
    if (!color) {
        throw new Error("A backgroundColor condition was missed");
    }
    return color;
  }
  })();
```

And no, that is not pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is wise to introduce an Enum that will hold the color values.

```
var ColorType = {
        Primary: "primary",
        Secondary: "secondary",
        Tertiary: "tertiary,
        ...
};
```

Then you can use this enum in switch case and you will avoid the typos and referrence to string directly. 
I think it will make the code less verbose and less prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a property of an object by using the property name as a string in square brackets.

(This example doesn't include the error catching you were using in your switch statement, but you can add that.)

```js
const CONSTANTS = {
  colors: {
    primary: "blue",
    secondary: "yellow"
  }
} 

function getColor(myPropName){
  // Pass dynamic property names like this
  return CONSTANTS.colors[myPropName];
}

console.log(getColor("secondary"));
```